# How to upgrade MySQL in a Bitnami Moodle stack?

Tags: moodle, bitnami

I have a Bitnami Moodle stack I use for local development. When I upgraded the Moodle version to 2.8.1, which is the current production version, the Moodle install page says I need to upgrade from MySQL 5.5.21 to 5.5.31.

Is there a way to simply upgrade MySQL within the existing Bitnami Moodle Stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami developer here,

Bitnami stacks contain everything you need to run the application. That way, all of the Bitnami-packaged applications you want to run will share a single instance of Apache, MySQL, PHP, etc which will save space and improve performance.

The best way to upgrade all Moodle Stack components (PHP, MySQL, Apache…) it's explained in the link below:
https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_Moodle#How_to_migrate_your_Moodle_installation.3f

It is strongly recommended that you create a backup before starting the update process. If you have important data, it is advisable that you create and try to restore a backup to ensure that everything works properly.

I hope it helps

Comment: Is the best way to upgrade MySQL within the existing Moodle stack, to follow the instructions for Migrating? I don't want to migrate - just want to upgrade MySQL instance within the existing setup. Is this possible?

Comment: Just to follow up... the information provided by David Gomez pointed me toward another solution which was to install another, later version, Bitnami Moodle Stack rather than try to tweak the existing one.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used bitnami but just been reading the FAQs, it looks like you can use ssh to open a terminal

https://wiki.bitnami.com/BitNami_Cloud_Hosting/Servers/SSH

Assuming its Ubuntu, you could try updating Ubuntu first to see if it updates mysql.

```
ssh username@yourbitnami.com
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If that doesn't work then you can use the mysql 5.5 ppa from Ondrej to upgade to the latest version of mysql 5.5 - something like this:

```
ssh username@yourbitnami.com
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```